# Difference between `httpd -k start` and `service httpd start`?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd, service

Normally, I restart `httpd` on my development "CentOS 6.5 (Final)" box using `service httpd restart`, or `service httpd stop` followed by `service httpd start` if I'm feeling paranoid.

However, after weeks of searching, tweaking, updating, and recompiling a "broken" PHP module (SpiderMonkey) to no avail, I have *on a whim* started apache using `httpd -k start` command -- **and the module suddenly appears!**

What's the difference? Can I correct the `service httpd start|stop|restart` behavior?

**NOTE**: In my initial attempt to correct the problem, I installed `php55w` from the webstatic repo. I'm *assuming*, had I had the whim prior to doing that, the solution (to restart using `httpd -k`) would have solved the problem, since that's how apache is normally restarted in production (where the module *works*).

Comment: What version of CentOS?

Comment: @sciurus 6.5 (Final)

Comment: ... I'm about to edit though. I just realized there are a few steps that may impact things.

Answer (score 1):

**examine the service**

service httpd start|stop|restart invokes a service wrapper, which effectively means that httpd itself is being triggered through scripted methods that likely do something more than *just* calling httpd.  an example of this is that they might write a PID file in a particular location in order to keep track of the currently running httpd process.

it's hard to say what might be causing the specific issue that you are seeing, but i suspect that inspection of the service wrapper would give you all the clues you need.  a typical location for your service wrapper might be /etc/init.d/httpd.

**confirm http used**

probably, you'll want to try 'which httpd' and compare that to the http path you find in the service wrapper.  maybe what you are seeing is a simple case of multiple competing httpd installations?

**check php config**

also probably relevant, if you are seeing the PHP module in some situations but not others, it could be valuable to use phpinfo() to see what php config is happening in the two situations.  make a script in your webroot like:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

and see what that turns up in each case.  perhaps your environment is somehow causing different php.ini to be used?

Comment: Good ideas (+1) ... still trying to determine what the meaningful difference is between the environments the process is run in. Any idea what ENV differences might be relevant?

Comment: if you are talking about the phpinfo() step, i would log the results to a file in each case and then diff the files to see what turns up.

Answer (score 1):

/etc/init.d/httpd does not call the httpd binary.  When you execute `service httpd start` the `deamon` program is called to start httpd in the background with the specified pidfile along with options from /etc/sysconfig/httpd.

```
start() {
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    LANG=$HTTPD_LANG daemon --pidfile=${pidfile} $httpd $OPTIONS
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch ${lockfile}
    return $RETVAL
}
```

Likewise, executing  `service httpd stop` uses the `killproc` function that's sourced from /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions to stop httpd.

```
stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc -p ${pidfile} -d ${STOP_TIMEOUT} $httpd
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && rm -f ${lockfile} ${pidfile}
}
```

Init scripts can be read like any other text file.  If you want to know what they're doing just look for yourself.

BTW, it's [recommended](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html) by Apache to use `apachectl` to control httpd.  Several of the init scripts are written from templates and may not necessarily take the best practices from the developer into consideration.

You can edit /etc/init.d/httpd to suit your needs but make sure you fully understand what you're doing before you do it.

Comment: Good info (+1). I've been poking around the `daemon` function it executes; but haven't been able to identify what the important difference is. When I manually execute the "final" command it runs (`/bin/bash -c 'ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /usr/sbin/httpd'`), it works properly. Is there something *general* in the file that could be running it with different permissions or restrictions? ... `phpinfo()` reports a different env; but I'm struggling to see which values would be relevant to the success of a single module loading ... Any further thoughts?

Comment: @svidgen When httpd is started using `daemon` the `-k start` option isn't used which may be causing your problems.  You can execute `/usr/sbin/httpd` without any options at all and it will start httpd, but that doesn't mean that it was started correctly.  `/bin/bash -c 'ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /usr/sbin/httpd'` by itself is just setting a soft limit of 0 for core dumps so that shouldn't affect loading modules.

Answer (score 0):

Your apache server is running in worker mode. Lots of php modules fail to load in worker mode. Change it to prefork mode, then `service httpd start` will also work.

Go to /etc/sysconfig/httpd file and block the line like below:

```
#HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker
```